# How to generate Strided IO access patterns using FIO?

Tags: local-storage, filesystems, benchmarking, file-system-storage

I am working on some experiments to observe the performance of storage devices. Specifically, I am looking for observing the performance under strided IO access patterns. Is there any way to do generate strided IO access pattern with FIO?

Answer (score 0):

use rw option to specify the stride. For instance to skip the stride of 16k
`rw=read:16k`